# Munkres' *Topology,* 2nd edition, Theorem 34.3 at page 218, confusion.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

I am currently learning point-set topology via the book “Topology, 2nd edition” written by James Munkres. Theorem 34.3 at page 218 states that a space $X$ is completely regular if and only if it is homeomorphic to some arbitrary product of interval $[0,1]$ in the uniform topology.

First things first, the definition of Munkres of completely regular space, is $T_{3 \, \frac{1}{2}}$ (Tychonoff space).

If this theorem is true, it implies that a Tychonoff space is metrizable and that a $T_4$ space is metrizable since it is homeomorphic to some arbitrary product of interval $[0,1]$ equipped with uniform topology which is metrizable. However we can find examples of $T_4$ space that are not metrizable.

What is the issue?

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure that $[0,1]^J$ is endowed with the uniform topology and not the product topology?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. the uniform metric is not a metric for an arbitrary product of [0,1]? By uniform metric I am talking about this metric:  p¯(x,y)=sup_a∈J_(min_x,y∈R_(d(x_a,y_a),1)) where d is a metric on R and J is an arbitrary index set. At page 124 of Munkres' Topology 2nd edition, it states that this is a metric for an arbitrary product of R.

Comment: What's stopping you for considering the same metric on subsets of $\mathbb R$, such as $[0,1]$? I think the theorem states: $X$ is  compl. regular iff $X $ is homeomorphic with $[0,1]^J$ (with the product topology) for some set $J$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. theorem 34.2 at page 217 states that if a family of continuous functions separate points from closed sets in X, then the function F: X to R^J (where J is an arbitrary index set)  defined by F(x)=(f_a(x))a∈J is an embedding of X in R^J. if f_a maps into [0,1] for each a, then F imbeds X in [0,1]^J. The proof was done with the uniform metric. After it says that the existence of a family of function that separates points from closed sets in X is equivalent as saying that the space X is Tychonoff.

Comment: So I guess that the theorem that I was first referring to was meant to equip [0,1]^J with a uniform metric.

Comment: no, that part with the closed sets and points separating family is in step 2 of 34.1, where the product topology is used, as stated in the beginning of that section. That part is then separated out out as 34.2/3 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munkres means this product $[0,1]^J$ to have the *product* topology, not the uniform metric topology. The product topology being the minimal one to make all projection maps continuous.

In the proof of Thm 34.1 the uniform metric *is* used, but that's for the countable base case (Urysohn's metrisation theorem), but it switches to the product topology later (step 2), and the generalisation 34.2 which has no separate proof is supposed to use the product topology, though Munkres is (IMO) quite unclear on this. I can understand your confusion.

Comment: theorem 34.2 at page 217 states that if a family of continuous functions separate points from closed sets in X, then the function F: X to R^J (where J is an arbitrary index set) defined by F(x)=(f_a(x))a∈J is an embedding of X in R^J. if f_a maps into [0,1] for each a, then F imbeds X in [0,1]^J. The proof was done with the uniform metric. After it says that the existence of a family of function that separates points from closed sets in X is equivalent as saying that the space X is Tychonoff.  So why is the theorem 34.3 not assuming that [0,1]J is being equipped with the uniform topology?

Comment: @Fogaing the embedding fact is for the product topology.

Comment: So if I understand well, theorem 34.2 is exclusive with the product topology on [0,1]^J?

Comment: I just reread my things and I completely understood my issues. @EvangelopoulosF.  Thank you very much to both of you. You saved my day!

Comment: @Fogaing .If  $J$ is uncountable then the (Tychonoff) product topology on $[0,1]^J$ is not  1st-countable, hence not metrizable.